# Resize Bordless Form is Glitchy

Tags: vb.net, winforms, lag, window-resize

My code to resize my form from the right hand side works, but is really glitchy or has a lot of lag. All my images blur and my drawn rectangles flicker while I'm resizing. Everything is normal however once mouseup.

I put the formborderstyle from borderless to sizable and the form resizes normally.

Hoping someone might be able to point out what is wrong with my code.

```
Dim myresize As Boolean = False
Dim cursorx As Integer
Dim cursory As Integer

Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.MouseDown

    If e.Location.X > Me.Width - 7 And e.Location.Y > 11 And e.Location.Y < Me.Height - 10 Then
        myresize = True
        cursorx = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Width
        cursory = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Height
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.MouseMove

    If myresize = True Then
        Me.Width = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - cursorx
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.MouseUp

    myresize = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure the `DoubleBuffered` property is true.

Comment: Thanks don, I think it has improved, but it still flickers pretty badly. I'm puzzled to why it works normally if I use the sizeable form, but doesn't work when I manually resize with a borderless form. I swear I had it working the other day, but that may have been a blank form I was working with, so flickers didn't really show.

Comment: You are bypassing an optimization built into TLP.  Try setting its CellBorderStyle property to "Single" and see if you now observe the same repaint expense when you use a sizeable border for the form.  Properly dealing with a borderless window takes a few tricks that are not built-in, google WM_NCHITTEST to find out more.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this works, but it brings up the window form border, which I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: I will look into WM_NCHITTEST however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the flickering, the form does not pass the DoubleBuffered property to its child controls, such as your TableLayoutPanel. Instead try adding a new class to your project that will doubleBuffer the tableLayoutPanel.

```
Public Class DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel
    Inherits TableLayoutPanel
    Public Sub New()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Build your project and the new version of the TableLayoutPanel will be in your toolbox as DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel. From there just use it as you would the TableLayoutPanel in your code.